# How Can I find the set $S$ written as infinite intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\displaystyle S = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left[0,\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right] \cup \left[\dfrac{1}{2n},1\right]\right)$

I need to determine set $S$. I don't know how should I solve this question properly ?

Can I simply take the limits for each term and then find set $S$ . Because we are dealing with infinite intersection here the corresponding sets will  and get smaller and smaller.

So I take the limit for each sequence  Since both $\dfrac{1}{2n+1}$ and $\dfrac{1}{2n}$ decreasing we will get

$S = [0,1]$. I don't know if this is right or not

Can anyone please explain me the proper way to solve such questions ?

Thank you .

Comment: Is the union of the two closed intervals a member of the intersection?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes Union is included between two closed members

Comment: You should add a pair of parentheses to remove any ambiguity. Also, in this case, it is already an infinite intersection.

Comment: The answer you suggest is not a subset of the set when $n=1$.  How can it be the intersection of all the sets?  What points are in every one of the sets $\left[0,\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right] \cup \left[\dfrac{1}{2n},1\right]$?

Comment: @saulspatz:oh Yes, you are right For $n=1$  $S = [0 , 1/3] \cup [1/2,1]$ and clearly [0,1] is not its subset , so my answer  is wrong . Can you tell me the correct way to solve this  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider what each item of the intersection excludes you will see that these are intervals of the type

$$\left(\dfrac{1}{2n+1},\dfrac{1}{2n}\right ).$$

You are left with the union of zero with

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left[\dfrac{1}{2n},\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\right]\right ).$$